# How do I write a postgres stored procedure that doesn't return anything?

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

How do I write a simple stored procedure in postgres that doesn't return a value at all?
Even with a void return type when I call the stored procedure I get a single row back.

```
CREATE FUNCTION somefunc(in_id bigint) RETURNS void AS $$
BEGIN
   DELETE from test_table where id = in_id;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the function that returns value, it's the `SELECT` you used to call it. If it doesn't return any rows, it doesn't run your function.

Answer (score 6):

You can achieve "nothing returned" by abusing set-returning functions:

Simple function:

```
create function x () returns setof record as $$
begin
return;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Now you can:

```
# select x();
 x
---
(0 rows)
```

In case it doesn't work for you (sorry, I'm using 8.5), try with this approach:

```
# create function x (OUT o1 bool, OUT o2 bool) returns setof record as $$
begin
return;
END;
$$ language plpgsql;
CREATE FUNCTION
```

The parameters are irrelevant, but:

- You need > 1 of them
- They have to be named

And now you can:

```
# select * from x();
 o1 | o2
----+----
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 5):

You are doing just fine. You dont need to add anything else.

The result of the row is null, so it is a void return.

I don't think theres something you can do about that. Checking my void functions all of them are just like yours.

returns void as $$ and no return statement in code block.

Comment: But how can that method be called?

Comment: SELECT * FROM void_function();

Comment: It's perhaps easier to use `PERFORM void_function();`.

Comment: PERFORM only works inside a pl/pgsql function. You use it when you want
to discard the result of a SELECT